# SQL: Run one SELECT query and then another SELECT query on the last query?

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I want to run the first query on the data list and then the second on the data that is selected by the first query. Needless to say this is not working out. How do I go about doing this?

```
SELECT *
FROM data_list
WHERE USAGE_TIME > 1530 AND USAGE_TIME < 2030
SELECT *
FROM data_list
WHERE USAGE_DATE = #12/07/2013#;
```

I also tried making another Query and selecting from the first completed Query, this did not work either.

Each Query runs fine on its own, but together... I am obviously doing it wrong... I am very new to SQL and have started picking it up to deal with a large data file I need to look at. Thanks!

Comment: What you need actually? a single result or two diferent results?

Comment: I just needed one well filtered result, AK47's answer is correct. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to write 2 different select statements. Instead you can have multiple filters (conditions) in you `WHERE` clause.

I hope you want this:

```
SELECT *
FROM data_list
WHERE USAGE_DATE = #12/07/2013#
AND USAGE_TIME > 1530 AND USAGE_TIME < 2030;
```

Comment: Not totally agree with your comment. But should not repeat same mistake twice. You can mark my ans as useful, if you have got your answer.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're complicating the situation. You can simply combine the conditions in the `WHERE` clause.

Here is the query you're looking for:

```
SELECT *
FROM data_list D
WHERE D.USAGE_TIME > 1530
    AND D.USAGE_TIME < 2030
    AND D.USAGE_DATE = #12/07/2013#
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using another query you can just use another `and` in the same query.

```
SELECT *
FROM data_list
WHERE USAGE_TIME > 1530 
AND USAGE_TIME < 2030 
AND USAGE_DATE = #12/07/2013#;
```